# jQuery.Lazy(): Plugin is not loading my 'li' contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lazy-loading

The [Lazy](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) plugin doesn't work fine for me. I've even added `alerts` to find where the problem is, but everything is ok for me. I try to use [this](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_make-use-of-effects) effect of the plugin for my gallery.

[Here](http://royayeketab.ir/gallery.html) is my website page where I use jQuery.Lazy().

**HTML:**

```
<div class="gallery-box col-md-9">
  <div class="col-md-11 pull-right">
    <ul>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image1.jpg" title="Item 1 title ..." data-desc="Item1 a small cake baked in a cup-shaped foil or paper case" rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb1.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء عادل فردوسی پور</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image2.jpg" title="Item 2 title ..." data-desc="Item 2 A cake made of sweetened cottage cheese or cream cheese, eggs, milk, sugar, and flavorings." rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb2.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء هنگامه قاضیانی</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image3.jpg" title="Item 3 title ..." data-desc="Item 3 A small, chocolate-covered candy with a hard or soft center." rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb3.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء امیر شهاب رضویان</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image1.jpg" title="Item 1 title ..." data-desc="Item1 a small cake baked in a cup-shaped foil or paper case" rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb1.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء عادل فردوسی پور</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image2.jpg" title="Item 2 title ..." data-desc="Item 2 A cake made of sweetened cottage cheese or cream cheese, eggs, milk, sugar, and flavorings." rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb2.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء هنگامه قاضیانی</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image3.jpg" title="Item 3 title ..." data-desc="Item 3 A small, chocolate-covered candy with a hard or soft center." rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb3.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء امیر شهاب رضویان</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image1.jpg" title="Item 1 title ..." data-desc="Item1 a small cake baked in a cup-shaped foil or paper case" rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb1.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء عادل فردوسی پور</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image2.jpg" title="Item 2 title ..." data-desc="Item 2 A cake made of sweetened cottage cheese or cream cheese, eggs, milk, sugar, and flavorings." rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb2.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء هنگامه قاضیانی</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image3.jpg" title="Item 3 title ..." data-desc="Item 3 A small, chocolate-covered candy with a hard or soft center." rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb3.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء امیر شهاب رضویان</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lazy">
        <a href="images/gallery2/image1.jpg" title="Item 1 title ..." data-desc="Item1 a small cake baked in a cup-shaped foil or paper case" rel="lightbox[group1]">
          <img style="width:200px; height:145px;" src="images/gallery2/thumb1.jpg" alt="Image description for search engins" />
          <h4>جشن امضاء عادل فردوسی پور</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.gallery-box ul > div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.gallery-box li {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  min-height: 280px;
  display: block;
}

.gallery-box li {
  min-height: 205px;
  padding: 9px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.gallery-box li:last-child {
  margin-left: none;
}

.gallery-box li h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('li.lazy').lazy({
      effect: "fadeIn",
      effectTime: 2000,
      threshold: 0,
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: try to use lower version of jquery.

Comment: @eisbehr I edit it, but it doesn't work fine and also I want li to load lazily not image

Comment: @Leothelion I check it with lower jq but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Ahh. Okay. But this is not how it works. You can lazy load the `li's` with Lazy, but then you need a resource where you can load the content from via `AJAX`. You can't lazy load html code which is already in the page ...

Comment: No, jQuery 3 is fine. You don't need a lower version @Leothelion.

Comment: In console there is error _jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function_ so i thought we should give a try.

Comment: Try this :$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.lazy').lazy({
      effect: "fadeIn",
      effectTime: 2000,
      threshold: 0,

    });
});

Comment: @eisbehr aha! I dont know how can I use ajax, can u help me how can I use it?

Comment: I can make you an example how you could lazy load the whole `li`. But this is a bit more complex as this. ;) What do you have as backend? `php`? @mimi

Comment: @Leothelion it is not error its warning and because I didn't adding owl plugin to this page I didn't added link in header

Comment: @eisbehr after I convert PSD to HTML, I wordpressed it.

Comment: Ohh wait, and another question. Do you really want to lazy load the data (which means to **load** the whole content only when the user scroll to them), or do you only want the fade-in effect, as seen on the example page of my plugin? (*the second one is easier*)

Comment: @mimi sometimes it can be issue as might be plugins are conflicting.

Comment: @eisbehr no I want to lazy load the data and also effect , both of them :D

Comment: Okay, please wait a moment ...

Comment: @eisbehr ok :D thanks for helping.

Comment: There you go! No problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP here!

Okay, you whish is to lazy load the whole `li` contents with [Lazy](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy). This is possible in general. But you have to think about what you want to do. It is no problem to lazy load content in general ...

You will need a backend where you can get the data from. Maybe a simple `php` script. You will post some data to the script and it will return the `html` for you.

For our example, the script would be look something like this:

```
if( isset($_POST["id"]) && is_numeric($_POST["id"]) ) {
    echo '<a href="images/gallery2/image' . $_POST["id"] . '.jpg" title="Item ' . $_POST["id"] . ' title">';
    echo '  <img src="images/gallery2/thumb' . $_POST["id"] . '.jpg" />';
    echo '  <h4>جشن امضاء عادل فردوسی پور</h4>';
    echo '</a>';

    die();
}
```

Pretty simple. There are now two ways to make the loading happen with `Lazy`. We start with the complex one first.

---

**Way 1: Use a 'custom loader'**

Custom loaders are a way to create own loader functions for `Lazy`. You have to implement everything by your own here, but you are more flexible on the other hand. We will name our custom load `ajaxLoader` to be simple

First we need to change your html elements. We need an `data-loader` attribute, to specify which loader we want to use. And we add some data, we want to post to your script, the `data-id`. So the `li` tags will look like this:

```
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajaxLoader" data-id="1"></li>
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajaxLoader" data-id="2"></li>
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajaxLoader" data-id="3"></li>
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajaxLoader" data-id="4"></li>
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajaxLoader" data-id="5"> ...
```

Now we create our instance of `Lazy`, and create our own custom loader. This looks more complex as it is (*you will find everything commented in my [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/q4raL8m4/) with more details*).

```
$(function() {
    $("li.lazy").lazy({
        threshold: 0,
        ajaxLoader: function(element, response)  {
            $.ajax({
                url: "yourScript.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {id: element.data("id")},
                success: function(data) {
                    element.html(data).fadeIn(3000);
                    response(true);
                },
                error: function() {
                    response(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is it! Now you got your self-written loader to load your `li` contents the *lazy way* over `AJAX`.

**[Wokring example.](https://jsfiddle.net/q4raL8m4/)**

When you need such loader on different instances of `Lazy` very often, you could think about to change your `custom loader` into a `plugin` in the future. It is pretty easy too but you don't have to include you custom loader into every instance manually. You can find a tutorial in the [git repo](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/tree/master/plugins#create-an-own-loader-plugin) or at the [project page](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/#plugins).

---

**Way 2: Use the `AJAX` Plugin of Lazy**

There are a [bunch of plugins](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/tree/master/plugins) for `Lazy` to load different content. There is even a [`AJAX` plugin](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/tree/master/plugins#ajax-loader) you could use. It is a bit easier to use, but is not so customizeable as a `custom loader`.

To use it, we change the `php` script a bit, from `$_POST` to `$_GET`:

```
if( isset($_GET["id"]) && is_numeric($_GET["id"]) ) {
```

The element will be changed a bit too. We set the `data-loader` to `ajax`, what is the name of the plugin, and set a `data-src` attribute, with the complete `URL` where we want to load the html data from.

```
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajax" data-src="yourScript.php?id=1"></li>
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajax" data-src="yourScript.php?id=2"></li>
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajax" data-src="yourScript.php?id=3"></li>
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajax" data-src="yourScript.php?id=4"></li>
<li class="lazy" data-loader="ajax" data-src="yourScript.php?id=5"> ...
```

The creation of the `Lazy` instance itself is then pretty easy:

```
$(function() {
    $('li.lazy').lazy({
        threshold: 0
    });
});
```

To make the effect working there too, with the `AJAX` plugin, you have to use the callbacks `beforeLoad` and `afterLoad` provided by `Lazy`. With this you can even create a loading animation or something. Even on the first way ...

---

I hope this will help you understand lazy loading and the usage of `Lazy`.

Comment: it's really helpfull :D