# Javascript Load more on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 30 div rows blocks in a page. Firstly I want to show only 5 rows and when user scrolls to 5th row then start loading next 10 rows. Repeat same till the end of the content.
In case of delay in content loading then show "Loading more products.... ".

Comment: your codes please...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.. Please go through the help page to understand how to make the best use of the community: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.Lazy(): Plugin is not loading my 'li' contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760148/jquery-lazy-plugin-is-not-loading-my-li-contents). There is a full example and explaination of what you need to do, to load contents the lazy way. I think this would help you.

Answer (score -1):

This is called "lazy load". You can search for it to see how you can implement it to your project.

Here one jQuery plugin for such as things

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Could you add an example for reference?

Comment: Although this may answer the question, at least post some code so your whole answer doesn't become completely worthless if/when the link is no longer valid.